# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090047 ("project name":id/content) for fragment FmMenu

Tags: java, android, xml, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception

Just wanted to share an issue that I have with a project that I am doing for a client.

Whenever I enter to my `IntroActivity` and press the button to take me to `MenuActivity`, it crashes.

**Here is the error log:**

```
02-16 18:49:49.393    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ No view found for id 0x7f090047 (com.wlodsgn.bunbunup:id/linear) for fragment FmMenu{b1e537f0 #0 id=0x7f090047}
02-16 18:49:49.393    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ Activity state:
02-16 18:49:49.423    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ Local FragmentActivity b1e1d1b8 State:
02-16 18:49:49.423    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ mCreated=falsemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
02-16 18:49:49.423    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ mLoadersStarted=false
02-16 18:49:49.443    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ FragmentManager misc state:
02-16 18:49:49.443    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity@b1e1d1b8
02-16 18:49:49.443    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@b1e1ed08
02-16 18:49:49.453    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ mCurState=1 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
02-16 18:49:49.453    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ View Hierarchy:
02-16 18:49:49.453    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1e23d08 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.473    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{b1e24280 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.473    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.view.ViewStub{b1e24da8 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102030e}
02-16 18:49:49.473    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{b1e25038 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.473    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{b1e2db28 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f09002f app:id/decor_content_parent}
02-16 18:49:49.483    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout{b1e2f758 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
02-16 18:49:49.483    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 02-16 18:49:49.513  1208: 1208 E/FragmentManager ]
    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{b1e2c058 VFE..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090042 app:id/drawer_layout}
02-16 18:49:49.513    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{b1e1fa90 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.523    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{b1e29568 VFED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090043 app:id/pager}
02-16 18:49:49.523    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ListView{b1e44148 VFED.VC. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090044 app:id/listView1}
02-16 18:49:49.523    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ListView{b1dd80b8 VFED.VC. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090045 app:id/list_slidermenu}
02-16 18:49:49.523    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b1e2fcd0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090030 app:id/action_bar_container}
02-16 18:49:49.533    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{b1e30898 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090031 app:id/action_bar}
02-16 18:49:49.533    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageButton{b1e39da8 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.533    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{b1e28a60 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-16 18:49:49.533    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{b1e43a50 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f090032 app:id/action_context_bar}
02-16 18:49:49.543    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-16 18:49:49.543    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a87ba8)
02-16 18:49:49.573    1208-1208/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wlodsgn.bunbunup, PID: 1208
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wlodsgn.bunbunup/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090047 (com.wlodsgn.bunbunup:id/linear) for fragment FmMenu{b1e537f0 #0 id=0x7f090047}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090047 (com.wlodsgn.bunbunup:id/linear) for fragment FmMenu{b1e537f0 #0 id=0x7f090047}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my `MenuActivity.java` where the error is located (Nearly at the end starts with `if (fragment != null) {` :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, OnActionExpandListener{

    /*private TextView texto;*/

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    String[] categoria = {
            "Jeans"
    };

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.veroxjeans1,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans2,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans3,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans4,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans5,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans6,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans7
    };

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        /*texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);*/

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // agregar un nuevo item al menu deslizante
        // Menu
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Contacto
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Catologo
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "Estrenos"));
        // old Contacto (Pedidos)
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        //lista
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoria );
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[3]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[4]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[5]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[6]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Abriendo Busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cerrando Busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        /*texto.setText("Buscando...\n\n" + s);*/
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        /*texto.setText(" \n\n" + s);*/
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu3_buscar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FmMenu();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FmContacto();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.linear, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("BunBunUp", "MenuActivity - Error cuando se creo el fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentos;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
        }

        public void addfragments(android.support.v4.app.Fragment xfragment){
            fragmentos.add(xfragment);
        }


        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_IMAGE = "imagen";
        private int imagen;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int imagen) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE, imagen);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                imagen = getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE);
            }
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView imagenView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**Here are the rest (If needed) of the files that are linked to `MenuActivity`** :

**FmMenu.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class FmMenu extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0a393d">

    <!-- Linearlayout to display Fragments -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="265dp"
            tools:context=".MenuActivity" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**lay_menufragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

**New error log:**

```
02-17 09:41:20.480      917-917/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ad9ba8)
02-17 09:41:20.560      917-917/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wlodsgn.bunbunup, PID: 917
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
            at com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MenuActivity.java:345)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

**Need more info, let me know**

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have found something.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.linear, fragment).commit();
```

As you see you try to replace the layout `R.id.linear` with your fragment. But the `R.id.linear` is the RelativeLayout you use in your **fragment_menu.xml**. You should replace the layout in your **activity_menu.xml** with the current fragment. So I would suggest:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

And in your **activity_menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0a393d">

    <!-- Linearlayout to display Fragments -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container">
```

**EDIT:**

For the new error: There is a problem with your memory. This often happens when `ImageViews` are filled by big ressources. So there is only one position where you use an `ImageView`:

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView imagenView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
            return rootView;
        }
```

As you see, your ***imagenView*** is filled by the resource ***imagen***

```
imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
```

Probably you get the `OutOfMemoryError` there. As a solution, try this:

```
try {
    imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    //fill your ImageView with something smaller .. maybe a smaller resolution
    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error: OutOfMemoryError")
}
```

Check your ***imagen*** too, whether there is a high resolution needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I apologize for responding late. I did the changes and it indeed cleared that error but now its displaying another one. Updated the post with the error (scroll down to the end of the post).

Comment: Sorry, its up now. Had to cut down the post a little since I was exceeding character limit.

Comment: By reading it, does it look like an out of memory error? Should I expand the memory in my emulator?

Comment: Yes indeed it looks like an out of memory error .. Did you try the app on a virtual device?

Comment: Yes, I am using android studio to run my virtual device.

Comment: Ok, try to expand the memory in your emulator or run it on a real device.

Comment: Ok, so I tried different settings in the AVD Manager increasing my memory up to 1.6gb with a VM Heap of 128MB and the app now enters the `MenuActivity` as I wanted from `IntroActivity`. Now the issue is that the app has become really slow.

Comment: Didn't see it, going to try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but where do I put that code? Under `imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);` or separate.

Comment: Just replace the given line throug the code I posted. It's located in the `onCreateView()` method of your `PlaceholderFragment`

Comment: Ok, so I was able to find the solution by reducing the resolution of the pics to a more suitable size and the app is much more stable. Appreciate your help!