# IllegalArgumentException ExpandableList with Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, illegalargumentexception

I have a nested lists. Where the parent is ExpandableListView and the Child is a viewpager with ListFragemnt.

Initially the childview is populated with Listitems in viewpager Listfragment. As soon as I collapse and reselect or Select another groupItem, it throws an error IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0137 (.../vp_incve_list) for fragment.

I tried debugging, Fragments are all replaced fine, fragmentmanger also returns fragment getByTag.

Not able to find where the problem is, below is snippet from my code. 
If anyone could help me pin point where things going wrong.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_incen_row, null);
        childHolder = new ChildHolder();

        childHolder.vpIncList = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vp_incve_list);

        convertView.setTag(childHolder);
    }
    else {
        childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    child = groupItems.get(groupPosition).getIncevList();


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(context, fragmentManager, child);
    childHolder.vpIncList.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    return convertView;
}
```

**SectionPagerAdapter**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = new CustomListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CustomListFragment.POSITION, position );
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0138 (.../vp_incetive_list) for fragment CustomListFragment{5f24536 #1 id=0x7f0d0138 android:switcher:2131558712:0}
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:503)
                                                                         at com.ibm.prepaidsalesapp.ui.home.IncentiveListAdapter.getChildView(IncentiveListAdapter.java:83)
                                                                         at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:736)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1666)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1149)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.P
```

Where IncentiveListAdapter is expandablelist adapter

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? Looks like one of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556277/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-0x7f090047-project-na), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665642/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-0x1020002-androidid-c) stackoverflow questions could help.

Comment: Can you add your second link in answers so that i'll mark it as answer.  Second linked helped .. thanks. I tried to viewpager without Fragment.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33132394/983364

Comment: thanks for giving me the answer! You can also edit the answer to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you pointed out yourself, you have used a viewpager without a fragment.

So, have a look at the answer of the following stackoverflow question.

[Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id/33132394#33132394)