# I get No view found for id ....for fragment YouTubePlayerSupportFragment which closes my application

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api

I am creating an application that should display within a fragment a youtube video by using YouTube API. I need to use a YouTubePlayerSupportFragment because i cannot extend my class to YouTubeBaseActivity (as I am already extending to AppCompatActivity). 
See error here

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f00a5 (com.[].[]:id/youtube_player) for fragment YouTubePlayerSupportFragment{d4c0c78 #4 id=0x7f0f00a5}
```

where i need to show the fragment

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class CharityPopup extends DialogFragment {

    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0.0f);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.charity_popup, container, false);


        Fragment fragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_player,fragment).commit();


        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setLayout(1000, 1000);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }

}
```

The corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/charity_popup">

    <fragment     android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Youtube class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;


public class YouTubeVideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;


    public static YouTubeVideoFragment newInstance() {
        YouTubeVideoFragment fragment = new YouTubeVideoFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    private void init(){
        initialize("AIzaSyCq543mRV_C5bxdcMxxkXN8U-_bacu8I-Y", this);
    }

    public YouTubeVideoFragment () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

}
```

and my youtube xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YouTubeVideoFragment">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure your corresponding xml's file name is `charity_popup`. If it is then check whether `charity_popup.xml` is in a folder named `layout` or in another folder named `layout-large`, etc i.e. you are not forgetting handling multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Based from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/), make sure that you have specified properly the layout in `setContentView()` of the `onCreate()` method of the `FragmentActivity`. This [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146302/5832311) also occurs when having **nested Fragments** and adding them with `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`. Here's another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556277/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-0x7f090047-project-na) for additional reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what fixed my problem was: **1** a better understanding of nested fragments (youtube.com/watch?v=V4kcdvzF5cY), also extremely important **AND 2.** the answer how to work with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. This is the link that saved me: [Struggling with Youtube Player Support Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302110/struggling-with-youtube-player-support-fragment?rq=1) . Look for the answer from CzarMatt AND the correction from Silmarilos. For my xml code for the fragment to be replaced with the youtube fragment:used a FrameLayout & android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlaye‌​rSupportFragment". Note I put there ...SupportFragment, and this is bacause I use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. IF you use YouTubePlayerFragment then you have to put: android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlaye‌​rFragment" in your FrameLayout.